# Embed node creation form using PHP

Tags: drupal-6

I have a content type called "enquiry". I want to embed the node creation form at various places throughout my website. How do I do this via PHP?

Answer (score 1):

sounds like a job for the webform module. if you really want to go the cck route you can try something like this:

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'store_review';
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$output = drupal_get_form('store_review_node_form', $node);
print $output;
```

ref: http://drupal.org/node/464906

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'enquiry';
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$output = drupal_get_form('enquiry_node_form', $node);
print $output;
```